# Is it safe to access a reference object that will be updated in another thread in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

There were some similar questions on stackoverflow about that, but I did not quite get the answer to the case that I have at the moment:

- I have some kind of a cache in a dictionary that is accessed in a multiple threads
- It does not matter if a a thread access the "old" version if an update is in process

  This is how I access the dictionary:

  ```
  if (m_Dictionary != null && m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
  {
      return await Task.FromResult(m_Dictionary[key]);
  }
  ```

  This is how I update the reference when some element is not in the cache e.g         (I can have multiple updates):

  ```
  var newDictionary = Load();
  lock (m_Lock)
  {
      m_Dictionary = newDictionary;
  }
  ```

So the question is: will I run into some issues with this, namely reading some partially updated reference? Since it's not 32 bit value (it can run on 64 bit architecture) it seems to me that it's not safe as atomicity is not guaranteed. Will it be enough then to change all the read access from variable to this method:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> GetDictionary()
{
    lock (m_Lock)
    {
       return m_Dictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want a dictionary that's thread safe- use a `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Is `m_Counterparts` and `m_Dictionary` the same thing?

Comment: Reference assignment operations are guarnteed to be atomic in .Net

Comment: So that means if I do var dictionary = m_Dictionary, I won't ever get wrong (mixed bytes or something) reference?

Comment: @Ilya: that is correct, *but* it should be made [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) to ensure assignment is propagated between threads.

Comment: What can happen if it is not volatile then? A thread will be able to use the old value even after it's updated (this is not a big issue for my case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is unsafe:

```
if (m_Dictionary != null && m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    // this could still throw KeyNotFound because 
    // it can be a different Dictionary than in the previous line
    return await Task.FromResult(m_Counterparts[key]);
}
```

for  that reason you would have to surround it with a `lock (m_Lock){}` too.

But your requirements should be met with:

```
var localDictionary = GetDictionary();  // a local copy is thread-safe

if (localDictionary.ContainsKey(key))   // or TryGetvalue
{
    return await Task.FromResult(localDictionary[key]);
}
else ...
```

Comment: +1 I didn't realize OP was swapping the dictionary instance on write, so my answer didn't make too much sense. I would also add that there is even no need to lock at all if the dictionary reference is read into a local variable first (presuming that each `Load` call creates a new instance which is not accessible by anyone else).

Comment: Yes, I just edited that solution in. Still, the provided code is to fragmentary to judge if this covers everything.

Comment: I have augmented the code to assign to local variable from a field, removed all the locks, and made the m_Dictionary volatile as Jon Hanna suggested. Are there any other considerations I should take into account? (loading of data always creates a new dictionary)

Comment: @Ilya: The only additional benefit of `TryGetValue` is that it checks for presence *and* returns the value in one step, i.e. it's slightly faster.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik - no, from what we can see that should work. There is a timing (lag) issue but you stated _It does not matter if a a thread access the "old" version ..._ . You shouldn't need the `volatile` but it won't hurt either.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, I am reloading the cache if item is not found, so a second thread figures out that it has to reload as well even after the first update, I just risk one more query to a 3d party service. This is not any critical since this operation is not very frequent (almost no chance it will happen). But thank you very much for help

Comment: I didn't suggest making the dictionary volatile, I just pointed out that you needed there to be some memory barrier after the write, and lock was doing that. (You don't need the memory barrier at all with x86 IIRC, but there's no promise of that). Assuming reads are much more common than writes, the lock is a better way of having that barrier.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're updating the entire dictionary in one go, the actual access of the reference is safe.

> Since it's not 32 bit value (it can run on 64 bit architecture) it seems to me that it's not safe as atomicity is not guaranteed.

On a 64-bit architecture, 64-bit-aligned 64-bit values have atomic access. Reference accesses are always atomic.

However, there are two things that can still go wrong:

One of these is updates from one core not being seen with another. You don't have this issue since you write in a lock and .NET locks have an implicit memory barrier. (Indeed, you don't need a full lock, a volatile write will suffice).

The other is races between reads. the `m_dictionary` of one read may not be the `m_dictionary` of the next. Read it into a local variable, and then act upon that local.

Comment: Are you sure volatile would be enough in this case? (I got that I made it wrong with not assigning locally). I knew about it, but everyone say it's very hard to get it right, so I decided to go with write lock...

Comment: You need something that causes a memory barrier after the write. Lock is a good approach, `VolatileWrite` isn't much safer and does complicate the reasoning, while having the variable `volatile` would penalise reads, and I assume reads are more plentiful than writes, so using `lock` to get the memory barrier is a good approach.

Comment: What do I risk if I just remove the volatile altogether? Is the only problem that one of the threads can read the old value, or it's something more drastic? Since the assignment is guaranteed to be atomic and the only two operation I have is update the reference, read the reference now?

Comment: Potentially you could have a thread read a stale copy of the value. It'll read that old value atomically, so it won't blow up, just act on the out-of-date value. Having the memory barrier (whether from `volatile`, `VolatileWrite`, `MemoryBarrier()` or `lock` with `lock` being the simplest and one that doesn't penalise reads) ensures that doesn't happen.

Comment: Does that also mean if I have very few writes and don't care if the thread reads the old value for some time, then I can just drop all locking mechanisms and rely only on assignments being atomic? P.S. Thank you for help, by the way, this clarifies a lot of things

Comment: If you really don't care that some threads could be reading old (potentially very, very old) values, then yes, that would be safe. Assuming that being able to look up the dictionary is useful enough to be worth doing at all though, then having the memory barrier after the write is probably better though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93699/discussion-between-ilya-chernomordik-and-jon-hanna).